# SQL grouping sets riddle

Tags: sql, set, grouping

Given a 'sorted by row' list (of n=4 elements for example) like:

F1,F2,F3,F4
F1,F2,F3,F5
F1,F2,F3,F6
F1,F2,F7,F4
F1,F2,F7,F5
F1,F2,F7,F6

in which every element is a field of a database table defined as:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB (F1 CHAR(1), F2 CHAR(1),  F3 CHAR(1), F4 CHAR(1), F5 CHAR(1), F6 CHAR(1), F7 CHAR(1));
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES ('A','B','C','D','E','F','G');
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES ('A','B','C','X','E','Y','G');
INSERT INTO TAB VALUES ('A','B','Z','X','E','Y','Q');
```

I would like to group by all possible grouping sets ('2 raised to 4' grouping sets), row by row, excluding grouping sets already evaluated from previous rows, in order to not get duplicates and to not use 'distinct' or 'union' sql statement for performance reasons (table tab is very large indeed).
For example, for the first row I can use the statement:

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3,F4, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F3,F4)
```

but for the second row, I cannot use the following statement, as it gives duplicates with the previous one:

```
SELECT F1,F2,F3,F5, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F3,F5)
```

At the end I would like to get all 104 distinct rows resulting from the:

```
/*104 records, bad performance for very large tables due to UNION statement 
and overhead in evaluating already evaluated groups*/

SELECT F1,F2,F3,F4, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F3,F4) UNION 
SELECT F1,F2,F3,F5, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F3,F5) UNION
SELECT F1,F2,F3,F6, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F3,F6) UNION
SELECT F1,F2,F7,F4, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F7,F4) UNION
SELECT F1,F2,F7,F5, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F7,F5) UNION
SELECT F1,F2,F7,F6, COUNT(*) FROM TAB GROUP BY CUBE(F1,F2,F7,F6)
```

I would like to find a kind of rule that lets me use 6 standard SQL statements without evaluating already evaluated groups (may be using grouping sets in some way?)

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Standard SQL, no specific relational database

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to group by all possible grouping sets ('2 raised to 4' grouping sets), row by row, excluding grouping sets already evaluated from previous rows, in order to not get duplicates

You can use `cube` and filter out results you don't want:

```
select t.*
from (select f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, count(*)
      from t
      group by cube (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7)
     ) f
where ( (case when f1 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when f2 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when f3 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when f4 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when f5 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when f6 is not null then 1 else 0 end) +
        (case when f7 is not null then 1 else 0 end)
      ) = 4;
```

Comment: The output must be the same as the query I posted

Comment: @user1630809 . . . (1) This does what you ask for.  (2) Your question has no desired results.  (3) Columns have only one name.

Comment: No, it does not. Your query gives a completely different output, made of 8 columns and 95 rows. The desired output has to be of 104 rows and 5 columns ("At the end I would like to get all 104 distinct rows resulting from the:...").

Comment: I put this question on https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4047564/math-behind-this-sql-problem. I can find a practical answer to this specific example, but not a generic algorithm, which is what I need.